# EntityFramework core error: Invalid column name 'Id' en relación muchos a muchos

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Recibo el siguiente error al hacer una relación de muchos a muchos en entity framework core:

Invalid column name 'Id'.
Invalid column name 'Id'.

Las tablas que estoy relacionando se llaman candidato y alerta. La tabla de relación se llama candidatoAlerta:

[image: candidato]

[image: alerta]

[image: candidatoAlerta]

El modelo de alerta es:

```
    public int IdAlerta { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }  
    public ICollection<CandidatoAlerta> CandidatosAlertas { get; set; }
```

El modelo de candidato es:

```
    public int Id { get; internal set; }
    public string nombre{ get; set; } 
    public ICollection<CandidatoAlerta> CandidatosAlertas { get; set; }
```

El modelo de candidatoAlerta es:

```
    public int IdAlerta { get; set; }
    public Alerta Alerta { get; set; }
    public int IdCandidato { get; set; }
    public Candidato Candidato { get; set; }
```

En el databaseContext estoy usando fluentApi para relacionar los modelos con los nombres de las columnas de la base de datos:

```
    public DbSet<Candidato> Candidatos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Provincia> Provincias { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Alerta> Alertas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CandidatoAlerta> CandidatosAlertas { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<Candidato>().ToTable("Candidato","candidato");

        builder.Entity<Candidato>().Property(c => c.Id).HasColumnName("Id_Candidato");
        builder.Entity<Candidato>().Property(c =>  
                                           c.CorreoElectronico).HasColumnName("Correo_electronico");

        builder.Entity<Alerta>().ToTable("Alerta", "candidato");
        builder.Entity<Alerta>().Property(c => c.IdAlerta).HasColumnName("Id_Alerta");
        builder.Entity<Alerta>().Property(c => c.Nombre).HasColumnName("Nombre");

        builder.Entity<CandidatoAlerta>()
               .HasKey(bc => new { bc.IdAlerta, bc.IdCandidato });
        builder.Entity<CandidatoAlerta>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Alerta)
            .WithMany(b => b.CandidatosAlertas)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.IdAlerta);
        builder.Entity<CandidatoAlerta>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Candidato)
            .WithMany(c => c.CandidatosAlertas)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.IdCandidato);
   }
```

El codigo que añade la alerta es:

```
 using (IUnitOfWork uow = GetUowInstance())
            {
                try
                {                           
                    Alerta alerta = new Alerta();
                    alerta.EstablecerDatosAlerta("test");

                    uow.Alertas.Add(alerta);
                    uow.Commit();
                }
```

Alguien puede hecharle un vistazo seguro que es una tonteria... yo llevo varias horas y nada....

Comment: Probe tu codigo en un proyecto de consola y me marco un detalle el EF que la tabla Alerta no tiene definida una llave asi que le agregue esta linea: `builder.Entity<Alerta>().HasKey(x => x.IdAlerta);`  he inserte una alerta y funcion todo bien.

Comment: perfecto, tienes razón gracias!

Comment: Con eso quedo arreglado tu error?

Comment: sí, con eso quedó arreglado.

Comment: Perfecto, responderé tu pregunta para que no quede abierta y si algún otro usuario se topa con esto pueda tener alguna ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probé tu código en un proyecto de consola y me marco un detalle  EF que la tabla `Alerta` no tiene definida una llave así que le agregue esta linea:

```
builder.Entity<Alerta>().HasKey(x => x.IdAlerta);
```

he inserte una `alerta` y función todo bien.